# When to use input restricted deque vs output restricted deque?

Tags: data-structures, deque

I understand that a deque is a double-ended queue, that is, insertion and deletion can be performed at both the front and rear of the queue, but there are additionally input and output restricted deques, and I'm not grasping when to use these two variations. I've found resources that describe the two structures, but don't provide more information beyond their implementations.

When should an input restricted or output restricted deque be used? Does one provide specific permutations that the other can't?

Answer (score 0):

Its depend upon the application.

This two types of deque is divided based on application. For Example : for Palindrome-checker we need input restricted queue only not as output restricted queue. So this two types used based on our application.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. Can you provide an example of when an output restricted deque would be used?